# Will a promise exit the execution prematually without await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Here is how the `await` is used:

> The keyword await makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result.

If app doesn't want to `await` until a `promise` settles and returns (such as update non-critical backend database), is it OK to call the `promise` without `await`? May a `promise` called without `await` exit prematurely before the promise is completely finished?

Comment: What is "app" in your question? `Promise` does not really care whether it's `await`ed or not. Regardless of anything promise constructor callback runs entirely.

Comment: Do you want to keep timeout for certain operation in your promise OR do you want the cancel the promise itself? If yes, Promise cancelling is not yet supported, you might need to introduce timeouts to handle.

Comment: "May a promise called without await exit prematurely before the promise is completely finished?" Exit from what? Could you clarify your question with an example (be it pseudo-code if necessary) of what you are struggling with? It's quite unclear if you want to simply call a method that returns a Promise without using that Promise at all, or if you want to have some way to cancel the asynchronous task that got wrapped in the Promise.

Comment: It is React Native mobile app. For better user experience, some operation such as update non-critical backend database doesn't have to wait for return value of promise. Skip await makes sense as long as the promise will not be exit prematurely without `await` keyword.

Comment: I read one online post which says the promise process may exit prematurely without `await` keyword.

Comment: You mean like it would timeout itself without doing what it was supposed to do? Nope that won't happen. And yes, you can very well make calls to methods that return Promises (such as `fetch`)  without having to actually await it if you don't care about the result of that method (though it would probably make for a bad design to not catch errors). Also, please [edit] your question so that what you want is stated more clearly, current answers seem to have missed the point completely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836893/1169519

Comment: `Kaiido`, a thoughtful answer. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly Yes, You can do.
`await` is when you need an asynchronous process.

If you just need to execute and don't need to wait for the process, then You can just call promise without await. Then the process won't wait and keep working for the next things.

However, be sure to handle rejection for this. You may need `Promise.catch`. Otherwise, You would see the `unhandled promise rejection` error when there is rejection from promise and it may be hard to debug.

Answer (score 6):

A promise is just a way of encapsulating the idea of getting some value in the future.

You don't "call" a promise.

You can either use a promise directly

```
const somePromise = someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise()
somePromise.then(functionToCallWhenValueIsAvailable);

function functionToCallWhenValueIsAvailable(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Or you can use it via await

```
const value = await someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise();
console.log(value);
```

`await` just makes the code simpler but it's doing the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `p` is an object of type [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). A promise is usually returned by a function that started an asynchronous operation. The function returns (the promise) immediately while the asynchronous operation is still running in background.

The promise object is used by the calling code to know when the asynchronous operation completes.

This can be done in two ways:

1. Using `.then()`/`.catch()`. This lets the main script continues and when the asynchronous operation completes a callback provided by the main script is invoked to learn about the way the promise has been fulfilled.

   ```js
   p.then((v) => console.log(`the async operation completed successfully and returned '${v}'`))
    .catch((err) => console.log(`the async operation failed with error: ${err}`));
   ```
2. Using `await` and `try/catch`. This way the main script is paused until the asynchronous operation completes. It resumes after the `await` statement on success or with the `catch` block if the async code throws an exception (the promise is rejected).

   ```js
   try {
     v = await p;
     console.log(`the async operation completed successfully and returned '${v}'`);
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(`the async operation failed with error: ${err}`);
   }
   ```

Neither of these methods affects the way the async operation is executed. It does its job in the background and, at some point, it completes (with success or failure).

If neither of these synchronization methods is used then the main code loses any way to learn about the faith of the asynchronous operation.

If the async operation completes with success, nobody knows when this happens and the value it returns is lost.

If it throws an exception then there is no way to catch it and, at least in Node.js, it terminates the execution of the entire script (because it is an unhandled exception and the interpreter does not know if it's safe to continue in such situations.)

Using one of the methods above, when an exception is thrown by the asynchronous code, the handler registered with `.catch()` (in the `.then()/.catch()` method) or the code block after `catch(err)` (in the `await/try/catch` method) is executed and the exception is passed to it (as `err`). It's up to these pieces of code to terminate the execution of the program or log the error and continue (as they do in my examples above).

Read more about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)