# Please point out the misfacts in my learning regarding Asynchronous Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to Javascript and Ascynchronous programming, and a few things confuse me, please point out the misfacts in my learning.

- Callbacks of an Asynchronous function are put in a message queue and
  executed via event loop.
- Asynchronous execution is non-blocking, done
  via event loop.
- Functions like `setTimeout` are asynchronous.
- Asynchronous functions are blocking, only their callbacks are
  non-blocking.

If any of the above are wrong, please elaborate it.

Comment: Everything executed in a JS thread is blocking, always. It's just that the actual tasks executed asynchronously are not executed by JS, but when the callback is executed, it's blocking the thread.

Comment: async functions are not blocking

Comment: @JaredSmith What!? The tasks executed by file system or whatever are not blocking, but JS is executed in a single thread, and it certainly always is blocking any other JS execution.

Comment: @Teemu  this is why greater clarity is needed. If you put an `await` in an async function, *execution does not stop and wait*. Control will pass right thrugh the return statement of the function, as I'm sure you know, it essentially registers a callback in the microtask queue. There is a lot of confusion in the wild (and arguably in the answers so far) on this point.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, and JS is blocking until the registration will be done (a very short period of time, though), then ofcourse continuing its thread as long as there is something to execute.

Comment: @Teemu again, we're arguing semantics here and only us being very specific (or the OP asking a more specific question) will solve the impasse because we are both correct in terms of the facts: yes a function (async or not) will block while it's executing. Even when called as a callback it will block while it is executing. But, and this is crucial to my point, *lots of people think that the `await` statement in an async function blocks until resolution* and that is simply not the case. So it depends on what the OP meant, I interpreted it one way and you another.

Comment: @JaredSmith You're right, we both know what is going on. I've explained `await` [in this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64109322/1169519) in more details, @Ajay you can take a look at that answer, it clarifies how `await` works.

Answer (score 5):

> Callbacks of an Asynchronous function are put in a message queue and executed via event loop.

**No.**

There are *generally* two kinds of asynchronous functions - ones that take some sort of callback to run when they are done and ones that produce a Promise as a result.

### Callback-based functions

This is an example of a callback-based function:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("foo"), 0);

console.log("bar");

/* output: 
bar
foo
*/
```

`setTimeout` will delay a callback to be executed later. Even with a timeout of zero milliseconds, it still schedules the callback until *after* the current execution is complete, so the order is:

1. `setTimeout` schedules the callback.
2. `console.log("bar")` runs.
3. The callback with `console.log("foo")` runs.

There isn't a *message* queue, there is a queue of *tasks* to execute. As a brief overview, the event loop takes one task from the queueand executes it to completion, then takes the next one and executes it to completion, etc. A simple pseudo-code representation would be:

```
while(true) {
    if (eventQueue.hasNext()) {
        task = eventQueue.takeNext();
        task();
    }
}
```

[See here for more information on the event loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459913/)

With all that said, the event loop has more bearing on `setTimeout` than many other callback-based functions. Other examples of callback based functions are jQuery's `$.ajax()` or the Node.js `fs` module for file system access (the non-promise API for it). They, and others, also take a callback that will be executed later but the bounding factor is not the event loop but whatever underlying operation the function makes. In the case of `$.ajax()` *when* the callback would be called depends on network speed, latency, and the server which responds to the request. So, while the callback *will* be executed by the event loop, so is everything else. So, it's hardly special. Only `setTimeout` has a more special interaction here, since the timings might be imprecise based on what tasks are available - if you schedule something to run in 10ms and some task takes 12ms to finish, the callback scheduled by `setTimeout` will not run on time.

### Promise-based functions

Here is an example:

```js
async function fn(print) {
  await "magic for now";
  console.log(print);
}

fn("foo")
  .then(() => console.log("bar"));

/* output: 
foo
bar
*/
```

(I'm omitting a lot of details for now for illustration.)

Promises are technically an abstraction over callbacks tailored towards handling asynchronous operations. The `.then()` method of a promise takes a callback and will execute it *after* the promise gets resolved, which also happens after the asynchronous operation finishes. Thus, we can sequence together execution in the right order:

```js
async function fn(print) {
  await "magic for now";
  console.log(print);
}

fn("foo");
console.log("bar");

/* output: 
bar
foo
*/
```

In a way, promises are sort of callbacks because they are here to replace them and do it in broadly the same fashion. You still pass callbacks to be executed when something succeeds or fails. [But they aren't *just* callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539815).

At any rate, a callback given to a promise is *still* delayed:

```js
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log("foo"));
  
console.log("bar");


/* output: 
bar
foo
*/
```

But not via the same event queue as the one `setTimeout` uses. There are two queues:

- macrotasks queue - `setTimeout` places things in it, and all UI interactions are also added here.
- microtasks queue - promises schedule their things here.

When the event loop runs, the microtasks queue (so, promises) has the highest priority, then comes the macrotask queue. This leads to:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("foo")); //3 - macrotask queue

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => console.log("bar")); //2 - microtask queue
  
console.log("baz"); //1 - current execution


/* output: 
baz
bar
foo
*/
```

At any rate, I don't think I'm comfortable saying that promise-based functions work via callbacks. Sort of yes but in a reductionist sense.

> Asynchronous execution is non-blocking, done via event loop.

**No.**

### What is "blocking"?

First of all, let's make this clear - blocking behaviour is when the environment is busy executing something. Usually no other code can run during that execution. Hence, further code is *blocked* from running.

Let's take this code as example:

```
setTimeout(taskForLater, 5000);

while (somethingIsNotFinished()) {
    tryToFinish();
}
```

Here `taskForLater` will be scheduled to run in 5 seconds. However, the `while` loop will *block* the execution. Since no other code will run, `taskForLater` might run in 10 seconds time, if that's how lot it takes for the loop to finish.

Running an asynchronous function doesn't always mean it runs *in parallel* with the current code. The environment executes one thing at time in most cases. There is no multi-threading by default in JavaScript, parallel execution is an opt-in behaviour, for example by using [workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).

### What is "asynchronous execution"?

This can mean a couple of things and it's not clear which one you reference:

1. Running through the body of an asynchronous function
2. Waiting until the underlying asynchronous operation is finished

In both cases the quoted statement is wrong but for different reasons.

#### The body of an async function

Async functions are syntactic sugar over promises. They use the same mechanism but just present the code differently. However, an async function *is blocking*. As a side note, so are promise executors (the callback given to a promise constructor). In both cases, the function will run *and block* until something causes it to pause. The easiest way to demonstrate it is with an async function - using `await` *will* pause the execution of the function and schedule the rest of it to be finished later.

Whole body is blocking:

```js
async function fn() {
  console.log("foo");
  
  console.log("bar");
}


fn();
console.log("baz");

/* output:
foo
bar
baz
*/
```

Pausing in the middle:

```js
async function fn() {
  console.log("foo");
  await "you can await any value";
  console.log("bar");
}


fn();
console.log("baz");

/* output:
foo
baz
bar
*/
```

As a point of clarification, *any* value can be awaited, not just promises. Awaiting a non-promise will still pause and resume the execution but since there is nothing to wait for, this will cause it to be among the first things on the microtask queue.

At any rate, executing the body of an async function *might* block. Depends on what the operation is.

#### The underlying asynchronous operation

When talking about "underlying operation", most of the times we mean that we hand off the control to something else, for example the browser or a library. In this case, the operation is not fulfilled by the current JavaScript environment we call something which will perform an operation and only notify the current JavaScript environment when it finishes. For example, in a browser calling `fetch` will fire off a network request but it's the browser handling it, not our code. So it's non-blocking but not by outside the execution environment.

```js
fetch("https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(joke => console.log(joke.setup + "\n" + joke.punchline));

console.log("foo");
```

With that said, we cannot even generalise what a given asynchronous operation will do. It might actually block the execution, at least for a while, or it might be entirely carried out in a separate process to the current JavaScript environment.

> Functions like `setTimeout` are asynchronous.

**Yes.**

Although, it's probably considering what is *like* `setTimeout`. Is it `setInterval`? Is it any callback-based asynchronous function? The problem is that the definition starts to become circular "asynchronous callback-based functions like `setTimeout` are asynchronous".

Not every function that takes a callback is asynchronous. Those that *are* might be considered similar to `setTimeout`.

> Asynchronous functions are blocking, only their callbacks are non-blocking.

**No.**

As discussed above, asynchronous functions *might* block. Depends on what exactly they do. For example `$.ajax` will initiate a network request using the browser, similar to `fetch`. In the case of `$.ajax` the function blocks while preparing the request but not after it's sent.

The second problem with the statement is that it's incorrect to call the callbacks non-blocking - *executing* them will certainly block the execution again. The callback is a normal JavaScript code that will be executed via the event loop when its time comes. While the task is running to completion, execution is still blocked.

If you mean that they are non-blocking in the sense that the callback will be put on the event queue, that's still not guaranteed. Consider the following illustrative code:

```
function myAsyncFunction(callback) {
    const asyncResult = someAsynchronousNonBlockingOperation();
    
    doStuff(result);
    callback(result);
    doMoreStuff(result);
}
```

Once `someAsynchronousNonBlockingOperation()` produces a value executing `callback` will not be scheduled for later but will be part of the synchronous sequence of code that processes that result. So, `callback` will be executed *later* but it will not be a task by itself but part of an overall task that encompasses `doStuff` and `doMoreStuff`.

Answer (score 1):

> Callbacks of an Asynchronous function are put in a message queue and executed via event loop.

Just in a queue (no messages). By asynchronous function I suppose you mean Promises. Remember `async` and `await` are syntactic sugar for Promises. They are execute **by** the event loop.

> Asynchronous execution is non-blocking, done via event loop.

Not really. Javascript is single threaded: whenever it starts executing your async code, it stays there as long as needed, unless you use Workers.

> Functions like setTimeout are asynchronous.

Like Promise, `setTimeout` and similars put the callback in a queue, which will be executed somewhere in the event loop (which may behave different for each kind of async functions).

> Asynchronous functions are blocking, only their callbacks are non-blocking.

Right!

Comment: Executing a callback will block as well as executing any JS function.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by blocking either async functions and their callbacks are both block else neither are.

Comment: I just wanted to understand by `callbacks` as `calling them` or, even better `adding them to some queue in the event loop`.