# Promise is blocking the thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to Node.js and was trying to understand `async` and `await` terms.

In the process, I got to know about `Promise`.

As I understood, with the help of it, we can make the function non-blocking.

I tried the following code,

```js
function get() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let out = 0
            const n = 9_900_000
            console.log('start looping')
            for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                out += Math.cos(i)
            }
            console.log('done looping')
            resolve(out)
            console.log('resolved')
        })
    })
}

console.log('before function calling')
r = get()
console.log('After function calling')
r.then(console.log)
console.log('in the end of file')
```

We find that **`get` is behaving like a non-blocking function**.

---

```js
function get() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let out = 0
        const n = 9_900_000
        console.log('start looping')
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            out += Math.cos(i)
        }
        console.log('done looping')
        resolve(out)
        console.log('resolved')
    })
}
console.log('before function calling')
r = get()
console.log('After function calling')
r.then(console.log)
console.log('in the end of file')
```

In other words, I removed the `setTimeout`.

**Now the `get` becomes a blocking function.**

Why is this happening?

Comment: function passed to the promise constructor is called _synchronously_.

Comment: Promises don't run on a separate thread or anything like that. A promise is *only* a notification mechanism for async tasks. But a lot of async tasks are just running on the same thread. You've written code that blocks the thread for a while, so it will...block the thread for a while. And then send a notification it's done via the promise.

Comment: There are no "threads" in JS, and once some syncronous code (like your `for`) started to execute it will run until it's finished. In the meantime no other code will be able to run because JS is in fact single threaded ...

Comment: Probably relevant: [Please point out the misfacts in my learning regarding Asynchronous Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65833787)

Answer (score 10):

The promise executor function executes synchronously, meaning that the code inside of the function below:

```js
new Promise(() => { // promise "executor function" that executes synchronously

});
```

executes when the Promise is created (the function is executed by the Promise constructor). In your second example, since your `for` loop is blocking, the promise is only created once your for loop completes, and only once it is created is it returned from `get()`, making it block the execution of any other code that comes after your call to the `get()` function.

In your first example, the promise executor function is still run synchronously when you create your promise, but this time, your calling `setTimeout()` with a delay of `0`. This makes the callback that you passed to `setTimeout()` get queued on the [task queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#tasks), and it will only execute once your main script has finished executing. This means that when your Promise is returned from your `get()` function, the `for` loop inside of your setTimeout() callback hasn't started running yet, as the callback passed to `setTimeout()` hasn't been executed/ran yet due to there still being code that needs to be run in the main script. As a result, your other code (such as the `console.log()`s) can run as there is nothing blocking them. Only once your main script is complete, then is your callback previously queued by setTimeout executed.

Keep in mind that Promises aren't a tool for making synchronous code asynchronous, they're more of a tool to help developers deal with code that *already* behaves asynchronously. If you need to perform a blocking operation in a background thread to prevent blocking the main thread then you can consider using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API).

Comment: Thanks, Nick. That is helpful and resolves my query.

Comment: @ShivKrishnaJaiswal No worries, if you feel like this answered your question you can mark this answer as "answered" by clicking the grey-checkmark in the top-left of the answer.